# Detect the renaming or deletion of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Is there a way to detect when a user

- renames, or
- deletes a worksheet?

I want to run some code if one of these events happens.

*what I have tried*

My tool uses a lot of event handlers so one thing I thought of was looping through all the sheetnames during each `Worksheet_Change`, but I don't think that is the best approach.

Comment: Not easily (in-built). Also not bulletproof, for example sheets can be deleted or renamed via code, not just via manual selection and deletion. The best option would be to stored the number of sheets and their names, then review these for any changes using an existing event (perhaps sheet activate).

Answer (score 1):

This approach goes under the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```
Public shArray1 As Variant
Public shArray2 As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strSht
Dim vErr
Dim strOut As String

'get all sheet names efficiently in a 1D array
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "shtNames", "=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND(""]"",GET.WORKBOOK(1)))"
shArray2 = Application.Transpose([INDEX(shtNames,)])
strSht = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(shArray2, , 1))

'exit here if first time code is run
If IsEmpty(shArray1) Then
    shArray1 = shArray2
    Exit Sub
End If

`check each sheet name still exists as is  
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(shArray1)
   vErr = Application.Match(shArray1(lngCnt, 1), strSht, 0)
   If IsError(vErr) Then
        strOut = strOut & shArray1(lngCnt, 1) & vbNewLine
        vErr = Empty
  End If
Next

shArray1 = Application.Transpose([INDEX(shtNames,)])

If Len(strOut) > 0 Then MsgBox strOut, vbCritical, "These sheets are gone or renamed"

End Sub
```

Comment: This kind of works.  The check only happens when a sheet is deactivated though, so if the current sheet is renamed or deleted, then I'd have to move sheets to trigger it.

Comment: You can change the Event to work on a more frequent basis. Suggest this would be overall for BAU use of your file though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the second part of your comment.  What's BAU?

Comment: Business as usual (bau). :) running an event continuously in the background  maybe a real drag on the performance of your file.